# How to show date and time from milliseconds in Android?

Tags: java, android, time, milliseconds

I want to display the date of a trip. In the application several trips are listed, each has a long value with the currentTimeMillis of its generation. I want to turn this **long** number into a date but the output is always something around 1970... Is System.currentTimeMillis() the right way to store the time of the trip generation?

```
Date date = new Date(trip.getStartTime());  // 195342322
SimpleDateFormat test = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
startTime.setText(String.valueOf(test.format(date)));
```

-> Output of startTime: 1970-01-01

Comment: It seems you trip start time is truncated somewhere. 195342322 milliseconds it is 1970-01-03. 195342322 is very small value to be right date, today milliseconds values is 1357406971942

Comment: Any chance you are internally converting from long to int then back to long?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) for simple formatting

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how `trip.getStartTime()` is implemented, however it returns a wrong value. `195342322` is Wed, 10 Mar 1976 21:45:22 GMT (you can check it [online](http://www.epochconverter.com/))

Since the only non-deprecated `Date` constructor accepts a `long` argument, I guess you used that. It's better to store the date(time) in a database-friendly way, such as ISO 8601. Note that if you store it on the client in a SQLite database, SQLite doesn't have a *time* type, and you have to use a *text* field for that.

Once you switch to the text representation for serialization, you will be able to get back a `Date` by using `SimpleDateFormat.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(trip.getStartTime());
Date date =calendar.getTime ();
```

as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis%28long%29) .

Comment: `setTimeInMillis` returns `void`. Your `date` will be empty :(